# How do I add a timeout if the http request fails?

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I have an app that requests json data from Firebase. I have implemented a condition for unsuccessful codes however when there is a lack of connection, the request doesn't time out. Is there a way to add a timeout so that the AlertDialog will appear?

```
return http
    .post('https://flutter**********.com/products.json',
        body: json.encode(productData))
    .then((http.Response response) {
      if(response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return false;
      }
```

`false` is returned when a different statusCode is received which in turn displays an AlertDialog allowing user to try again. It appears when code is deliberately broken but not when there is a lack of connectivity.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If a request times out (e.g. because there is no connection), there is no response from the server. Try this:

```
try {
    http.post('https://flutter**********.com/products.json',
    body: json.encode(productData))
    .then((http.Response response) {
        if(response.statusCode != 200 && response.statusCode != 201) {
            _processTimeout();
            return false;
        };
} on TimeoutException catch (_) {
    _processTimeout();
    return false;
}
```

Add whatever needs to happen in `_processTimeout()`.